# My grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1 does not obey backslash character and special expression

Tags: grep, gnu

I'm trying to follow a section in [The GNU Grep Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions) but my expression isn't working. Is it my grep version? Red Hat 5.5.

```
$ rm file
$ echo 'hello world' > file
$ grep 'hello world' file
hello world
$ grep 'hello\sworld' file
$
```

Returns nothing. grep-2.5.1-55.el5

Comment: Works with grep (GNU grep) 2.14

Comment: Does `grep  'hello[[:space:]]world' file` work?

Comment: [:space:] and [:blank:] work. But why doesn't \s work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special handling of `\s` was added in grep 2.6.3. [Commit message](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grep-commit/2010-07/msg00000.html)

Whenever possible, use the info docs that are on your system.  Just run `info grep`.

To get this behavior, try adding the `-P` flag to make it work in Perl regex mode.

Comment: I knew it must be the version number. I'll need to make do with this for now. Thanks to all contributions.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your issue with `GNU grep v2.5.1`.

However, when I use `-i` switch it worked:

```
grep -i 'hello\sworld' file
```

From the man page:

> -i, --ignore-case
>                 Ignore case distinctions in both the PATTERN and the input files.

It might be a bug in grep.

Comment: You are right. `-i` causes it to return the result I want. Curiously though, without `-i`, both `\S` and `\s` both fail to return expected results.